# Show the item name when selected the item id from lookup

Tags: axapta, x++, ax

Dummy needs a help : ))))) 
I have an empty Grid with 2 fields, ItemId and ItemName, ItemId has lookup key.
How to make it possible when I select some itemid from lookup table to show its ItemName  in another field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your table in the AOT, overwrite the modifiedfield method. 
For an example on how to overwrite, check the purchline.modifiedField method for example. 
Just add a case in the switch:

case fieldnum(YourTable, ItemId)
      this.itemName = inventtable::find(this.itemid).name();
      break;

Unless really necessary, adding both the itemId and itemName is not needed, as you are de-normalizing the database at the point. It is probably better to add a display method for the itemname to your grid.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly. I have one more question. Is it possible to do this task without code or not?

Comment: The name of the item is retrieved using the inventtable.name() method, so you need to call that method to retrieve it. I can't think of a way to do it without code. Personally, I would use a display method here and not add a field to the table, and you certainly need code for that.